# Forge Viewer: getExternalIdMapping() to return only certain dbIds from certain externalIds

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

```
this.viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => console.log(data))
```

This particular line gets everything. But I only need the dbIds of certain externalIds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to implement your own [user function](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/executeuserfunction-accepts-user-data) and calling the [getExternalIdMapping](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/PropertyDatabase/#getexternalidmapping-extidfilter) method of the property database that can actually be filtered for specific external IDs:

```js
function mapMyExternalIds(model, externalIds) {
  const filter = {};
  for (const externalId of externalIds) {
    filter[externalId] = true;
  }
  return model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction(function userFunction(pdb, filter) {
    return pdb.getExternalIdMapping(filter);
  }, filter);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```js
mapMyExternalIds(NOP_VIEWER.model, ["6949fe39-3e9a-4d4d-b7fe-71339c615138-00022318"])
  .then(map => console.log(map))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways depending on what exactly you need.  Here's what I've done.

```
function getDbIdFromExternalId(externalIds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping((d) => {
        //console.log("getDbIdFromExternalId Executed");
        let responseArr = [];
        externalIds.forEach(externalId => {
            if(d[externalId]) responseArr.push([d[externalId], externalId]);
        });
        resolve(responseArr);
      });
    });
}
/*Your external IDs in here*/
var externalIds = ['23287','23292','23291'];
/*response is set here*/
var response = await getDbIdFromExternalId(externalIds);
```

Expected value of `response` (with my autocad viewer):  `[[39675,"23292"],[39674,"23291"]]`

That way you can see the pair.  Notice I threw in a value that didn't map to anything, so the array was only populated with what it found.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have tried your method but the DevTools logs this error:
'ReferenceError: viewer is not defined'

Comment: Sorry, assumed you had set the viewer given your question already using viewer.  My viewer is defined as `viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);` from inside my Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer.  Perhaps given how you received responses in your question, try `this.viewer...`

Comment: I have set that in my initialiser too. I am just running into so many problems with this .getExternalIdMapping(). I have cleared my extension and did a new one. Could you please have a look at this current viewer extension of mine? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71270975/17559906)