# Autodesk Forge: Viewer Extension cant use .getExternalIdMapping()

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

```
class IBSProgressExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension{
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
    }
    load() {
        //For proof of concept project, I will simply store the externalIds here in a variable.
        const allExternalIds = [
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-0006879a',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-000688ee',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068961',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068963',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a78',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a0d',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a0f',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a11',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a13',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c2f',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c31',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c33',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b2e',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b30',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b32',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b34',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3e',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b36',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b38',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3a',
            '8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3c'
        ];

        this.viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => onSuccessMapping(data));

        function onSuccessMapping(data) {
            const resArray = [];
            allExternalIds.forEach(externalId => {
                if (data[externalId]) resArray.push(data[externalId], externalId);
            });
            console.log(resArray);
        };

        console.log('IBSProgressExtension is loaded.');
        return true;
    }
};


Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension("IBSProgressExtension", IBSProgressExtension);
```

Please have a look at my extension and please help me figure out why is this happening.
Every time i run it, the devtools logs: ViewerExtension.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getExternalIdMapping').

Comment: Most likely, this is being run before the model is actually loaded, so the `this.viewer.model` is undefined.  I see that this is a proof of concept.. can you elaborate on the desire and what you'll be doing with the result?  What will be firing the event to get the dbIds?  (e.g. a toolbar button click?)

Comment: My project: 
1. To get a few barcodes (the barcodes are the externalIds) from MongoDb if a property within each doc is not null.
2. To compare the barcodes with all the externalIds in my model.
3. Then, if (allExternalIds.includes(barcode)) {setThemingColor()}
@MattH

Comment: Okay, let me see if I can craft something to help out here.

Comment: I am hoping that the trigger will be every time the extension is loaded. No user interaction needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extensions get loaded **before** the model so the **getExternalIdMapping()** method does not have the model properties yet. To handle this scenario, we usually recommend using the **viewer events** such as [Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#geometry-loaded-event) to “catch” the moment when the model is available. It’s better to wait for the event. This will be fired when the model/drawing finishes loading.

**Instead of:**

```js
this.viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => onSuccessMapping(data));
```

**Try this:**

```js
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, (x) => {
            this.viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(data => onSuccessMapping(data));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this and see if it's helpful.  I tried to incorporate items from your comments to help you structure it out.

```
class IBSProgressExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super(viewer, options);
    this._externalIds = null;
    //Eventually will want to pass in your external IDs to this function, I assume:
    //this._externalIds = options.externalIds
  
    this._doStuff = () => {
      this.startDoingStuff();
    };
  }
  load() {
    console.log("loading extension");
    //For now, hard coded like your example.
    this._externalIds = [
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-0006879a",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-000688ee",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068961",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068963",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a78",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a0d",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a0f",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a11",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068a13",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c2f",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c31",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068c33",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b2e",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b30",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b32",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b34",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3e",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b36",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b38",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3a",
      "8a00f4c7-0709-4749-88b6-abb0ddccf965-00068b3c",
    ];
    //Not sure if this is truly the right event, but it worked when I tested on mine.
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_LAYERS_LOADED_EVENT, this._doStuff);
  }
  startDoingStuff() {
    console.log("startDoingStuff executing");
    this.getDbIds(this._externalIds).then((CombinedArray) => {
      this.setCustomColors(CombinedArray);
    });
  }
  setCustomColors(arrayOfIDs) {
    console.log("setCustomColors executing");
    var somecolor = "#7D5B51";
    var threecolor = new THREE.Color(somecolor);
    var vectcolor = new THREE.Vector4(threecolor.r, threecolor.g, threecolor.b, 1);

    arrayOfIDs.forEach((e) => {
      this.viewer.setThemingColor(e[0], vectcolor, this.viewer.getVisibleModels()[0]);
    });
  }
  getDbIds(externalIds) {
    console.log("getDbIds executing");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.viewer.model.getExternalIdMapping((d) => {
        //console.log("getDbIdFromExternalId Executed");
        let responseArr = [];
        externalIds.forEach((externalId) => {
          if (d[externalId]) responseArr.push([d[externalId], externalId]);
        });
        console.log("resolving", responseArr);
        resolve(responseArr);
      });
    });
  }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension("IBSProgressExtension", IBSProgressExtension);
```

Comment: I tried adding an event listener like you did but still not working. It will work sometimes when the document loads before the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this, I was trying to achieve 3 things at this stage.

1. Get the `externalIds` from `Mongodb`.
2. Compare the externalIds with the ones gotten from `getExternalIdMapping()`.
3. Get `DbIds` of those that matched.

Solved these by realising 2 and 3 can be put inside `a.then()` after `.loadDocumentNode()`.